# Count number of redirects in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy to fetch a list of URLs. Some of the urls are redirected to another <302>. What I want is to count the number of redirects that happen for a single url and also a complete set of all the intermediate redirection urls.e.g.

> Fetching - http://ign.com
>
> Redirected to - http://de.ign.com/
>
> redirect_count = 1
>
> url_set = ['http://ign.com', 'http://de.ign.com/']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is to handle 302 `httpstatus`,

```
handle_httpstatus_list = [200, 302, 404] # any other if you want
```

here is the example:

define you `items.py` as,

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class myItems(Item):
    redirect_count = Field()
```

Later on in your `spider.py`,

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from .items import myItems

class mainSpider(Spider):
    name = "crazyCrawler"
    allowed_domains = ['http://ign.com', 'http://de.ign.com/']
    handle_httpstatus_list = [200, 302, 404] # any other if you want

    start_urls = [
        "http://ign.com"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # spider
        sel = Selector(response)

        items = []
        item = myItems()

        item['redirect_count'] = 0

        if response.status == 302:
            item['redirect_count'] += 1
```

Now you can run,

```
scrapy crawl crazyCrawler -o items.json
```

Comment: Thanks... for the help. Figured it out my self. Some information is already exposed in the meta from the default "BaseRedirectMiddleware" in scrapy, rest I can handle as you described :)

Comment: You're welcome. What have been described in (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/downloadermiddleware/redirect.py) is detailed version of handling redirection in scrapy